# VBScript setting the _POST variable

Tags: vbscript

Is there an equal VBScript solution to PHP's

```
$_POST("user") = 12345;
```

I just need to set the $_POST variable to some value (which gets retrieved on the next page) and do not see any direct solution. ( note: I cannot use session, or self-submitting html form with post method.)

Thanks.

Comment: How do you go to the next page?

Comment: ..there is a response.redirect right now but I am open to better solution.

Comment: A `Response.Redirect` by definition makes the browser to do a GET request for the page. If you can't use a self-submitting form, you are out of luck. More info: http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=214#a4